# how to use angular js scope variable in html

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to pass value of scope variable returned from controller in html window.open, but the problem is i get some garbage value, please see the code below.

```
<header>
    <span class="item-title">{{x.name}}</span>
    <span class="list-item-note-sendmoney1" onclick="window.open('tel:{{x.phone}}', '_system')"><ons-icon icon="ion-android-call"></ons-icon></span>
</header>
<p class="swipe-item-desc">{{x.phone}}</p>
```

I want to pass `{{x.phone}}` to `window.open('tel:')` function.

Comment: x.phone is working outside window.open?

Comment: yes, the correct is displaying.

Comment: you want to dial number when user click on icon right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use onclick. Use ng-click. And put the JS code in the controller:

```
ng-click="openWindow()"
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.openWindow = function() {
    window.open('tel:' + $scope.x.phone, '_system');
}
```

Comment: Hi @JB, i knew that solution, but i thought there might be some way to have the scope variable in html directly.

Comment: sorry my bad, it worked, the problem was with `$scope.x.phone` as it was declared out of scope.